# Xpath to grab multiple segments within a table divide, seperated by <br>'s

Tags: xml, xpath

I've been working at this for a while and I'm not even sure I'm going in the right direction. Simple HTML example is below; What I'm trying to do is return only the lines that have 'Orange County' in them below. I currently am using `//table/tr/td[4]/text()[contains(.,'Orange')]`, which works, but only returns the first address in the `td`. Is there a way to grab all of the instances of `Orange`, (2 in this example)?

```
example here...
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        1. 
    </td>
    <td>
        John Doe 
    </td>
    <td>
        01/02/2001
    </td>
    <td>
        1111 Eastview St, Los Angeles, CA 12345
        <br>
        2222 Brookhurst St, Orange County, CA 12345
        <br>
        3333 Cherry St, Los Angeles, CA 12345
        <br>
        4444 Brookhurst St, Orange County, CA 12345
        <br>
        5555 Cherry St, Los Angeles, CA 12345
    </td>
    <td>
        (213) 555-1212
        <br>
        (213) 555-1212
        <br>
        (213) 555-1212
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your XPath is correct. Can you add the tag for the tool you use and your current code?

Comment: I'm currently only using chrome (browser) and an xpath extension `chrome://extensions/?id=mbigbapnjcgaffohmbkdlecaccepngjd`.

Comment: Actually, you're right. My original code is returning an array of the targetted items. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Andersson pointed out, my xpath is correct (`//table/tr/td[4]/text()[contains(.,'Orange')]`), it's returning an array of the items I was trying to grab.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this 
`//table/tr/td[4]/*[contains(text(),'Orange')]`